# How to exclude transitive dependencies of spring-boot-dependencies from maven import scope

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have the following in my Spring Boot application pom as per [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent):

```xml
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- Spring -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

I need to use use `dependencyManagement` and `<scope>import</scope>` because I need to use a standard corporate base pom.

However, it doesn't seem possible to exclude transitive dependencies of `spring-boot-dependencies`. In my particular case, Spring Boot `1.2.1.RELEASE` is bringing in a version of Jetty that is too new with respect to some of my other `<dependencies>`. I tried using an `<exclusion>` of the form:

```xml
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- Spring -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>

        <!-- Doesn't work -->
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

using [Maven 3.2.1's wildcard support](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html), but it doesn't seem to take effect.

Is there a solution to this problem other than explicitly overriding all the Jetty dependencies? There are many Jetty libraries and that approach would be quite brittle. Furthermore, it appears I would need to do the same with Jetty's transitive dependencies as well.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Spring Boot Maven Plugin 2.3.1.RELEASE documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/), to override individual dependencies, you need to add entries in the `dependencyManagement` section of your project **before** the `spring-boot-dependencies` entry.

```xml
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- Your jetty version dependency -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Spring -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Cool: answering a 5-year-old question with an actually very useful answer!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this [isn't possible with Maven import scope](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/MavenImportScope):

> The import scope can be used to include dependency management
>   information from a remote POM into the current project.  One of the
>   limitations of this is that **it does not allow additional excludes to
>   be defined for a multi module project**.

Likewise, there is a confirmation from the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-dependency-versions-with-maven):

> If you have added spring-boot-dependencies in your own
>   `dependencyManagement` section with `<scope>import</scope>` **you have to
>   redefine the artifact yourself** [...].

Comment: This might also be an option: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/exclude-on-scope-import-td5781856.html

Comment: how did you achive it finally? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @chaosguru I redefined the artifact. Its a pain, but this is more Maven's fault than Spring Boot's.